# Altium automatically adds footprint to new library component. How to solve it?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, software, symbol, library

I have a problem with Altium and i couldn't solve it.

When I add new symbol to my integrated library, by default it has 6 footprints and the symbol designator and comment is same every time (not Altium's default) and I should delete them every time to add my footprint and symbol. I want to change it back to the default (schematic symbol with no footprint, NO comment and default designator "*") please help me solve this problem.

[image: Properties window]

[image: default footprints added to schematic symbol]

Comment: I'm unsure what it is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Did you try re-naming Component_1 as something like "Jumper_1" and saving the library?

Comment: @Andyaka by default altium library symbol has no footprint, but in my altium new component has 6 footprints and I should delete them every time

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I tried but it's same

Comment: Did you confirm that the Component_1 no longer is in the library?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No, The component reference is "Component_1". Nothing is changed

Answer (score -1):

When you place that component on the schematic, you can select one of the six footprints, and that one footprint will be placed on the PC board.

You will find that many schematic components have multiple footprints associated with them - resistors may have footprints called axial0.4, 1206, 0805, ... for example.